# Issue with AWX not with command line

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I have a role in ansible working in command line but not through awx.

Here the role :

```
- name: Enable persistent logging
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/systemd/journald.conf
    regexp: '^#Storage'
    line: Storage=persistent

- name: Check directory
  ansible.builtin.stat:
    path: "{{ journal_dir }}"
  register: journaldir

- block:
  - name: Create directory
    ansible.builtin.file:
      path: "{{ journal_dir }}"
      state: directory
      mode: '0755'

  - name: Enable systemd-tmpfiles folder
    ansible.builtin.command: /bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix {{ journal_dir }}
    check_mode: no
    notify:
      - restart systemd-journald

  when: journaldir.stat.exists == false and ansible_distribution_major_version >= '7'
```

Here the notify code :

```
- name: restart systemd-journald
  ansible.builtin.service:
    name: systemd-journald
    state: restarted
```

*{{ journal_dir }} is /var/log/journal*

I have no issue when I run the playbook on my terminal, but when I run it with awx, I still have this error :

```
TASK [journalctl : Enable systemd-tmpfiles folder] *****************************
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "no command given", "rc": 256}
```

I have done test also with shell module, it's the same behaviour.

And I don't understand why.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I foud the issue, it seems I'm using an old version of ansible, so I had to remove the fqcn for the command module.

It works like this :

```
  - name: Enable systemd-tmpfiles folder
    command: /bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix {{ journal_dir }}
    notify: 
      - restart systemd-journald
```

my ansible version through command line is 2.9.27,ansible version of awx is 2.9.14.

[solution has been found here] : [Ansible cant run any command or shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431114/ansible-cant-run-any-command-or-shell)